# Ordered output for maven parallel build

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3

I am using maven version 3+ to build my project. I am using parallel builds by using the command:
**mvn -T 10 clean install**

This uses 10 threads and I get a 40%-50% decrease in build time. But at the same time, it messes up the output of the maven command and it becomes very difficult to make sense of. Is there a way I can get an ordered output or is their no way around the jumbled up console output?

Comment: If you think that parallel threads are writing to the log it is expected that the output is no more linear otherwise you would do a synchronisation to the logging output which would prevent real parallelization in the end. There is only a problem if you really have problem which you like to analyze...but for that you could change to single thread and analyse it...So ?

Comment: How many modules do you have in your build?

Comment: @khmarbause Thanks for your answer. I have about 30 modules in my project. And I do believe we can live with some unordered logging and go back to single thread in case of an issue.

Comment: In my opinion this is a failure of maven. They should have changed the logging output to prepend a thread number or something (maybe optionally). After all thread 2 that's running X,Y,Z modules should easily be able to know that it's thread #2 (or heck, give it a unique generated name or something), and prepend log output from that thread.
It could even splice it to different files or whatever maven wanted to architect as a solution.

But as far as I know, they didn't think this through, or consider it worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

While maven still can not separate the logoutput per thread (as of version 3.9.5), there's still a way to make the log more debugable.

In the logging properties (%M2_HOME%\conf\logging\simplelogger.properties), set these values:

> org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=**true**
>
> org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showThreadName=**true**

The first config will add the milliseconds for the entire build and the second one will add the name of each thread to each line of the output. This makes it alot easier to analyze the logfile.

(source: https://struberg.wordpress.com/2016/10/18/better-test-logs-in-parallel-maven-builds/)

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible with the Threading configuration used. The Threading is used only to get the files from repositories otherwise it is linear due to dependency unless your modules are independent in which case you would have created multiple build easily. You can disable the logging and print only errors in Thread mode.

Reference Link for linear execution: http://www.keensoft.es/en/speeding-up-maven-by-parallel-threads/

Comment: As the original poster wrote he/she has got an decrease in time by 40%-50% which means it is a good idea to use parallel build.  And your assumption writing that only the files from repository are getting in parallel is simply wrong. If you have situation like module A,B,C,D,...Z and module B depends on A and C on B and ...Z on Y than this will result in a linear build order..but usual projects are not that like...

Comment: I specifically put "unless your modules are independent", seldom they are independent and added reference link of linear execution claim